# Test returns null for NOT NULL field with default value

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have the below code:I'm using it a simple way to drive out the columns of the feature_set table, so would like air_conditioning, pool .. etc with a boolean value which defaults to 0.

However when I use a factory or instanciate it directly like below ->air_conditioning is always null, and I can't figure out why.I tested with a mysql Db and when I add a new row it defaults to 0 correctly. Am I missing something here, why arn't the default values of 0 set on the model instance.

```
class FeatureSetTest extends TestCase
{
    use RefreshDatabase;
  public function testCanCreateFeatureSetAndValuesDefaultToFalse()
   {
       $featureSet = new FeatureSet(['property_id' => '1']);
       $featureSet->save();

       $this->assertFalse($featureSet->air_conditioning);
   }
}
```

...

```
    public function up()
   {
       Schema::create('feature_sets', function (Blueprint $table) {
           $table->increments('id');
           $table->unsignedInteger('property_id');
           $table->boolean('air_conditioning')->default(false);
           $table->timestamps();
       });
   }
```

If I dd $featureSet after it's saved in the test I get:

```
 #attributes: array:4 [
   "property_id" => "1"
   "updated_at" => "2018-05-12 16:15:19"
   "created_at" => "2018-05-12 16:15:19"
   "id" => 1
 ]
```

If I do dd(DB::select(DB::raw('SHOW CREATE TABLE feature_sets'))); it outputs the below so 0 is set as the default and :

```
 CREATE TABLE `feature_sets` (\n
           `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,\n
           `property_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,\n
           `air_conditioning` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',\n
           `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,\n
           `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,\n
           PRIMARY KEY (`id`)\n
         ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_c
```

And finally If i put dd(DB::select(DB::raw('SELECT * FROM feature_sets'))); in my test I can see the default value is correctly set:

```
array:1 [
  0 => {#598
    +"id": 1
    +"property_id": 1
    +"air_conditioning": 0
    +"created_at": "2018-05-12 15:44:31"
    +"updated_at": "2018-05-12 15:44:31"
  }
]
```

//Feature Set Model.

```
<?php

namespace App\Models\Property;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class FeatureSet extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [];

    public function asFeaturesArray()
    {

        return [
            'air_conditioning' => [
                'title' => __('Air Conditioning'),
                'value' => $this->air_conditioning
            ]
        ];
    }
}
```

I dont understand why it doesn't give me 0 back for ->air_conditioning

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that `$featureSet->refresh()` is the answer for this, `->fresh()` above to just get the fresh values for the existing attributes that the model has where as refresh get a fresh version of all attributes - which includes my defaulted to 0 attributes.

fresh = Reload a fresh model instance from the database.
refresh = Reload the current model instance with fresh attributes from the database.

Solution was found here - https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/21449